# Liquidity "Syntax error", ok, but what/where?

Tags: smart-contracts, liquidity

I'm having problems with liquidity syntax... (I'm using the online liquidity-lang editor).

I'm trying to make a simple smart contract that adds items with history, think of it as a maintenance log for vehicles.

I'd like to add a ton of different features, like transferability, ownership, security, I'm even considering saving small pics of the items as Byte64 strings.... but I'm stuck.

What am I missing? I get an unexplained "Syntax error" on the last line.

Here's the code that's bugging me right now...

```
type event = {
  date: timestamp;
  value_str: string option;
  value_int: int option;
}
type item = {
  itemName: string;
  history: event list;
}
type archive = (string, item) big_map
    (*type owner = {
        ownerName: string;
        address: address;(* To be compared with Current.source *)
        ownedItems: (string, timestamp) map;
      }*)
type storage = {
  archive: archive;
}
let%init storage = {
  archive = BigMap [];
}

let%entry main
    (item_id, item)
    storage =
  let arch = Map.add item_id item storage.archive in
  let storage = storage.archive <- arch in
  [], storage
let%entry addEvent
    (item_id, event)
    storage =
  let storage = match Map.find item_id storage.archive with
    | None ->
        failwith("Item not found", item_id)
    | Some found_id ->
        let new_history =  event :: found_id.history in
        let new_item = found_id.history <- new_history in
        let new_archive = Map.update item_id new_item storage.archive in
        let storage = storage.archive <- new_archive in
        [], storage
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax error is an unterminated `let`:

```
  let storage = match Map.find item_id storage.archive with
    | None ->
        failwith("Item not found", item_id)
    | Some found_id ->
        ...
        [], storage
```

It should be `let storage = ... in ...`, but the `in ...` is missing.

Let the automatic indentation be a clue.

In the OCaml syntax, you can use `begin` and `end` to delimit things when necessary:

```
  let storage = begin
    match Map.find item_id storage.archive with
    | None ->
        failwith("Item not found", item_id)
    | Some found_id ->
        ...
        let storage = storage.archive <- new_archive in
        storage 
  end in
  [], storage
```

Actually, in this case, it isn't necessary:

```
  let storage = match Map.find item_id storage.archive with
    | None ->
        failwith("Item not found", item_id)
    | Some found_id ->
        ...
        let storage = storage.archive <- new_archive in
        storage in
  [], storage
```

The ReasonML syntax might be more familiar to you. Note the "RE" button in Try-Liquidity (next to "Compile".) Example:

```
  let storage =
    switch (Map.find(item_id, storage.archive)) {
    | None => failwith(("Item not found", item_id))
    | Some(found_id) =>
      ...
      let storage = storage.archive = new_archive;
      storage;
    };
  ([], storage);
```

Comment: In the end, I did as you and others in the Riot chat said and switched to the ReasonML syntax... I occasionally have to go to the reference, hit the _Try online_ button, convert to reason to make sure it's gonna be accepted but I'm saving on the headaches...